# QED in LaTeX Proof Environment

Tags: symbols, amsthm

When using the `proof` environment provided by the `amsthm` package, you get an empty square box at the end of your proof as the default QED symbol.

Question: Is there a way to make it automatically put "QED" for some proofs but not others? Essentially, can one create a second proof environment which puts a different symbol at the end?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{QED}`

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I should have been more clear. Is there a way to do this for some proofs but not others? I'm coauthoring a paper and my partner prefers the square but I prefer QED.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: in a single paper, there should be a unique QED symbol. I could understand different symbols for, say, nested proofs, but not QED in some proofs and the square in others.

Comment: @egreg Is that etiquette? To me, it seems useful for there to be different symbols, so the reader can differentiate between each author's work without it being explicitly mentioned every proof. Essentially what I want is two different proof environments, each with their own QED smybol.

Comment: `\renewcommand` the `\qedsymbol` locally.

Comment: Everything is possible (even if it is bad style...) but since the LaTeX format defines no standard `{proof}` environment you should tell us something about your setup.

Comment: @campa We are using \usepackage{graphicx, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, amsfonts, mathtools, tikz-cd, biblatex, comment, tikz}

Comment: @campa I understand that this may be "bad style" but I intend on submitting this paper in my portfolio to grad programs, so I would like whoever may read them to actually know where I contributed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a new environment based on `proof` environment and modify the `\qedsymbol` locally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newenvironment{proofa}{%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{QED}\proof}{\endproof}
\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  This is a proof with the original square symbol.
\end{proof}

\begin{proofa}
  This is another proof with ``QED'' symbol.
\end{proofa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Environment wrappers should better use the internal macros `\proof` and `\endproof`. Makes for better error messages sometimes. (And wouldn't work otherwise with some environments.)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: OK, I have edited the code@campa